# https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator display image on preview but image not share in twitter

Tags: html, twitter, meta-tags, twitter-card

i have write below code in my html page

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@name" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Twitter - image share" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="View the album." />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5510/14338202952_93595258ff_z.jpg" />

<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=Test twitter image share&url=http://mysite.test" target="_blank">Twitter Share</a>
```

but image shown in `preview card` and i tweet the post image not shown on twitter post page

any other step for `twitter card` or any mistake that i can done in code so help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Your image maybe to large.  summary_large_image is 280px 150px
This has helped me in the past.

https://static.agorapulse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Twitter-image-sizes.png